# I can't make it "see", Antigua and Bermuda, i think because of the spaces?

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
function ff_CselRegion_action(element, action)
{   
    country = ff_getElementByName('CselCountry');
    state   = ff_getElementByName('CselState');

    var America_NorthArray = new Array('Antigua and Barbuda', 'Canada', 'Greenland', 'USA', 'Mexico');
    if (element.value == 'none') {
        // drop countries
        while (country.options.length > 0)
            country.options[country.options.length-1] = null;
    } else {
        // get the matching array
        var selectedArray = eval(element.value+'Array');

        // drop supernumerous option
        while (selectedArray.length < country.options.length-1)
            country.options[country.options.length-1] = null;

        // add the new options
        country.options[0] = new Option('Select Country', 'none', true, true);
        for (var i = 0; i < selectedArray.length; i++)
            country.options[i+1] =
                new Option(selectedArray[i], selectedArray[i]);
    } // if

    // drop states
    while (state.options.length > 0)
        state.options[state.options.length-1] = null;
} // ff_CselRegion_action
function ff_CselCountry_action(element, action)
{
    state = ff_getElementByName('CselState');

    var stateArrayAntigua and Barbuda = new Array(
    'Saint George', 'Saint John', 'Saint Mary', 'Saint Paul'

    var selectedArray = eval('stateArray'+element.value);


    if (selectedArray == null) {
        while (state.options.length > 0)
            state.options[(state.options.length - 1)] = null;
    } else {
        // drop supernumerous option
        while (selectedArray.length < state.options.length-1)
            state.options[state.options.length-1] = null;

        // add the new options
        state.options[0] = new Option('Select State', 'none', true, true);
        for (var i=0; i < selectedArray.length; i++)
            state.options[i+1] = new Option(selectedArray[i], selectedArray[i]);
    } // if
} //ff_CselCountry_action
```

I am trying to find a solution for (`var stateArrayAntigua and Barbuda`) because it has spaces and cannot "see" the 'Antigua and Barbuda' at the (`var America_NorthArray`). As I am new in programming, I would appreciate your answers to be as simple as possible. Thank you in advance

P.S. I searched on the internet but I haven't managed to work it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have spaces inside variables' names. Make it `var stateArrayAntigua_and_Barbuda` and you're good to go (if there's no other problems with your code).

If you'd like to to learn this more in depth, you may want to read [this](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-identifiers-es6) but basically you'd better use latin letters digits, `_` and `$` in variables' names.

PS in the lines

```
var stateArrayAntigua and Barbuda = new Array(
    'Saint George', 'Saint John', 'Saint Mary', 'Saint Paul'
```

you also got a syntax error: the closing bracket is missing.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I thought of it before and tried but the problem is both var must be Antigua_and_Barbuda. If this happens, the in the drop down list it will appear as such and I don't want this. I want it to appear as Antigua and Bermuda (without underscore)

Comment: @GalanopD what do you mean by "both var must be Antigua_and_Barbuda"? Which both? If you want 2 variables, create 2 (with different names), but you can't have a variable with a name containing spaces, sorry. You can create an object with a property with such name, like: `window["stateArrayAntigua and Barbuda"] = ...` or `var myNewObject = {"stateArrayAntigua and Barbuda": some value}`.

Comment: You are correct for the closing bracket, it is my mistake during copy/paste. The code above works ok, it is tested when it comes to a country with just a single name. But when the country has more.... i dont know how to work it out!

Comment: var stateArrayAntigua_and_Barbuda = new Array(
        'Saint George', 'Saint John', 'Saint Mary', 'Saint Paul', 'Saint Peter',
  'Saint Philip', 'Barbuda', 'Redonda'
    );

Comment: Now if I change
 
var America_NorthArray =  new Array('Antigua and Barbuda', 'Canada', 'Greenland',
  'USA', 'Mexico'
 );

and put underscore to 'Antigua and Bermuda' it will appear on my drop list menu and i don't want that! That is the problem. Thank you

Comment: Just to help understanding, First var at line 35, Second var at line 6. They "communicate"

Comment: @GalanopD what do you mean by "communicate"? In the line 6 you have a *String* `'Antigua and Barbuda'` which is ok and which has nothing to do with the name of your *variable*. You can keep spaces in your String but have to remove them in your variable name..

Comment: ok, both the _String_ 'Antigua and Barbuda' and the 'var stateArrayAntigua and Barbuda' MUST be the same. But, in this case the 'var stateArrayAntigua and Barbuda' generates an error as it has spaces. So, if don't use spaces and make it like 'var stateArrayAntigua_and_Barbuda' or 'var stateArrayAntiguaandBarbuda' I MUST change the _String_ accordingly to  'Antigua_and_ Barbuda' or  'AntiguaandBarbuda' it will appear on my drop down list as such. The _String_ appears on the drop down list and it MUST remain as  'Antigua and Barbuda'. But then, what happens to the var?

Comment: @GalanopD I'm afraid, if you don't explain any *specific reason* why they "must" be the same, I can't help you. It's just this simple: you say that the String has to have spaces; a variable name can't have spaces; and you say that they must be the same. Contradiction. What can I (or anybody else) do for you? Variable names *can't* have spaces; you can work around only in the other 2 requirements: either make those different or add "_" to the String and remove them when needed (when you form the drop list menu)

Comment: Thank you. I will follow your advises and find my way around.